# SharePoint Central Admin not opening

Tags: central-administration

I have installed sharepoint site on my local machine with standalone installation.
After that i have changed my machine name then my sharepoint site was not opening. Then i revert the changes to original machine name and reinstalled sharepoint but still the same problem. My central administration is not opening. When i try to open central admin it shows 404 page not found error. where all my installation and configuration was successfull. and i also checked the application pool. All pools are in a started state.
Please Help....

Comment: did you checked if application pool/iis is not stopped?

Comment: Checked that the pool is actually running in IIS? :) Aslo try clicking "browse" from the application pool overview in IIS

Comment: ya i checked application pool. all pools are started

Comment: check whether windows authentication is enabled for the site in iis.

Comment: Deepu : how to check whether windows authentication is enabled for the site in iis?

Answer (score 1):

Since you re-installed SharePoint, you can try and see if the port number for central admin is still the same by running:

```
Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration
```

in SP2010 Management Shell.

Comment: my central admin port is 8080. and i am trying to login to the same port but no success...

Comment: You should also check in IIS to make sure that Central Admin is pointing to the right Physical path (ie. virtual directory folder). It is in the advanced settings in IIS for the site. Here is a link that may help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/tfsadmin/thread/4d8945e8-ae0a-4587-be03-78a8f85718eb

Answer (score 1):

Renaming a computer with Sharepoint on is never a good idea and even though you renamed it back I suspect a SID is stored somewhere in your config database.

Anyways, running through the Sharepoint Products and Technologies wizard should sort out your problem. I hope you saved your farm pass phrase because this is where you will need it.

I suggest you create your central admin site on a new port.

Answer (score 1):

with a port number of 8080 I'm wondering it's possible that there is a conflict? As mentioned earlier a different port number would be a good start

Comment: Port 9999 seems to be where SP CA ends up often.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has an article about renaming your server for a stand-alone installation:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261986(v=office.14).aspx

Basically, after you have renamed the server, run in PowerShell:

```
Rename-SPServer
```

Pass the new server name in as a parameter.

Make sure you do iisreset /noforce as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reprovision Central Admin. You can just run a standard repair and reprovision Central Admin in place (you will get asked if you want to change central admin server. Don't). Should solve the problem.